# In RavenDb, are static indexes opportunistically used by generic session.Query<TDocType> calls

Tags: c#, ravendb

So, I have queries in my application, and realized some queries were consistently under higher load.  In particular, augmenting client subscriptions happens frequently (although, perhaps not outside the hours of 8:00am and 5:00pm).

I have a document type

```
public class AggregateSubscription
{
    public Guid UserId {get; set;}
    public Guid AggregateId {get; set;}
    ...other fields
}
```

and I've added an index

```
public class AggregateSubscription_ByAggregateId : AbstractIndexCreationTask<AggregateSubscription>
{
    public AggregateSubscription_ByAggregateId()
    {
        Map = docs => from d in docs select new { d.AggregateId };
    }
}
```

Now, to query using this index I know I can

```
var results = session.Query<AggregateSubscription, AggregateSubscription_ByAggregateId>()
    .Where(x => x.AggregateId == ...);
```

My question is, will a generic query of <AggregateSubscription> with a Where clause on the AggregateId property automatically make use of this static index?
e.g.

```
var results = session.Query<AggregateSubscription>()
    .Where(x => x.AggregateId == ...);    //will this detect that it can use _ByAggregateId index and use it?
```

After adding the index, I would really like if ravendb's query engine, when slicing and dicing the Where fields into lucene syntax, would detect there's a static index that matches, and utilize it.
From the documentation, it seems dynamic indexes work this way (the same shaped query resolves to the same dynamic index), but I can't tell if there's support for the scenario with static indexes that I described above.

I'm hoping someone with familiarity around either ravendb's query implementation or strategy could let me know how much to expect of the static indexes.

Alternatively, if you could point me to where I can see index **usage** stats I could empirically check the results.  All I see is processing statistics for indexes, not the index actually being used by queries.

edit 1: added context around question

edit 2:
I've found some promising evidence.
When constructing the Query `IRavenQueryable<T>`, it shows the `query.IndexQueried = "dynamic/AggregateSubscriptions"`.  But that's client side.

After executing the query, the stats show `RavenQueryStatistics.IndexName = AggregateSubscription/ByAggregateId`.
So it looks like ravendb server side does in fact make use of the static index if one exists.
I'll go an answer my own question, but I'm open to if anyone can answer my original question (ravendb implementation details, overall strategy, or index query usage stats via something like Raven Studio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empirically I'm able to show that, although on the client side, the index name showed it was using a dynamic query, the `RavenQueryStatistics` returned by the server after querying shows it ultimately found a match and used the static index.

Additionally, digging into ravendb's source on github, I was able to find where this strategy is implemented, :
the method `public DynamicQueryOptimizerResult SelectAppropriateIndex(...`

https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/blob/v3.0/Raven.Database/Queries/DynamicQueryOptimizer.cs#L50

It gets pretty hairy when qualifying potential index matches (lines 91-336), but even just looking at the setup (lines 64-75) the primary qualifier for finding index matches is a normalized set of fields used by the query.